# Setting UIScrollView's Position from another ViewController

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview, contentoffset

I am trying to set the position of a UIScrollView by using contentOffset as such:

```
- (void) navigateToTableViewPosition:(CGPoint)contentOffset {
    NSLog(@"Position set method gets called...");
    NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(contentOffset));
    [mainScrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
}
```

I call this method from another view controller before I dismiss it, and everything checks out. I pass the argument correctly, and the method gets called (checked it with NSLog), but the scroll view does not move...

What is funny is that when I call this method from the view controller, in which it is located, it works fine. Only when I call it from another view controller, it stops working.

Just for future reference, here is the calling method:

```
MainViewController *mainView = [[MainViewController alloc] init];
[mainView navigateToTableViewPosition:contentOffset];
```

Content offset is a CGPoint I set beforehand. It doesn't matter here; besides, it gets passed correctly anyways.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,  You have to `send notification` from other `viewcontroller` when you want to change ..

```
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"changepostion"        object:NSStringFromCGPoint(CGPointMake(contentOffset.x, contentOffset.y))];
```

in `mainviewcontroller`

```
  -(void)viewDidLoad

  {
     [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self];
         [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self    selector:@selector(navigateToTableViewPosition:) name:@"changepostion" object:nil];

  }

- (void) navigateToTableViewPosition:(NSNotification *)notification
  {
        contentOffset =CGPointFromString([notification object]);

   NSLog(@"Position set method gets called...");
   NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromCGPoint(contentOffset));
    [mainScrollView setContentOffset:contentOffset animated:YES];
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set the properties of a view which is not visible. If you are using iOS5+ you can implement the offset setting in the completion in the view dismiss completion block.

Answer (score 0):

Use **delegate** for backward messaging in view controllers.

Refer [Basic Delegate Example](http://coderchrismills.wordpress.com/2011/05/05/basic-delegate-example/) link for more reference.

Your are making new instance of viewcontroller which will call method but will have no effect.

Comment: That seems to be the answer, but I cannot figure out how to set the delegate. A couple months ago I did something similar, and I remember it was very simple. I set a UIView's delegate to another view controller and then just called methods like [delegate method:argument]; But I don't remember how I did it, and I do not know how to apply it in this situation.